# Laravel multitenant how to use api routes for tenant

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multitenant Laravel web app, in which I have 2 panels, a central panel and a tenant panel. I am developing it and the idea is for a central panel to manage each building. And each tenant has its own modules that it manages. I have successfully created the two panels. But I'm a little stuck at this point, I want to access tenant routes, let's say with Postman, in the same way as I access routes that can be in a simple Laravel application (api.php), I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me with this?

I want to make this because when I try this `http://foo.localhost:8000/login` on the postman I get `"message": "CSRF token mismatch.",`

This is the web.php routes

```
Route::redirect('/', 'login');

Auth::routes();

/**
 * Route group middleware
 * 
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // DASHBOARD
    Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

    // USERS MANAGEMENTS
    Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
});
```

and this is tenant.php

```
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    // Route::get('/', function () {
    //     return view('auth.login');
    // });
    Route::redirect('/', 'login');

    Auth::routes();

    
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
        // DASHBOARD
        Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

        // USERS MANAGEMENTS
        Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
        Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

        // PRODUCTS MANAGEMENTS
        Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
        ...
    });
});
```

`NOTE:`  I have installed [tenancyforlaravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3)  to make the tenants

when I do `php artisan route:cache` I get this error ` LogicException

Unable to prepare route [login] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned the name [login].

at \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php:247`

How can I fix this problem? also, I want the tenant route to make as api route, and to make call like this`foo.localhost:8000/api/v1/login`

Answer (score 1):

RouteServiceProvider set api prefix and middleware to api routes. You should to that manually in tenant.php.

```
Route::name('api.')->prefix('api/v1')->middleware([
    'api',
    'auth:sanctum',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    
    Route::redirect('/', 'api.login');

    Auth::routes();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is usefoul at some point but still i see this error `Unable to prepare route [login] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [login].` any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: You can add name prefix to route group and use 'api.login'. Updated my answer. BTW, I didn't understand why you set GET login route as API. It should be either a view path, or handled by front-end framework unless you pass whole HTML from controller. POST login should be an API route.

Comment: I already have tryed this method before `You can add name prefix to route group and use 'api.login'` but is not working and show me same error